# How to retrieve all cookies using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, cookies, selenium-webdriver

I am using below code but its not displaying all the cookies.
can anyone help with java code?

```
Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();

Iterator<Cookie> itr = cookies.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()){
    Cookie c = itr.next();
    System.out.println("-----Cookies Detail-----");
    System.out.println("Cookie Name: " + c.getName()  + "\n\tCookie Domain: " + c.getDomain() +  "\n\tCookie Value: " + c.getValue() +  "\n\tPath: " + c.getPath()+  "\n\tExpiry Date: " + c.getExpiry()+  "\n\tSecure: " + c.isSecure());
}
```

Comment: you will get only the cookies for the current domain..

Comment: @SajanChandran Is there any way to retrieve 3rd party cookies?

Comment: if the cookie is set by another domain, then "no"

Comment: @Ron How do you know it's not showing all cookies? `getCookies()` should give you all the cookies used on current domain including the ones do not belong to same domain

Comment: @Saifur getCookies() gives cookies for current domain only,I want to retrieve 2rd party cookies as well.

Comment: @Ron I suspect that's not true. It does return you any cookies used on the domain [including from another party]